# Algorithm to calculate UIScrollViews landscape contentOffSet from portrait?

Tags: uiscrollview

Does anyone know an algorithm to calculate a scrollViews landscape contentOffSet if the portrait contentOffSet was provided?

and then vice versa if the landscape contentOffSet was provided to enduce the portraits contentOffSet

Thanks in advance

Comment: contentOffset should hopefully not change during rotations.  Bounds should, but scrollviews maintain a constant offset.

Comment: Consider this scenario.. Place some text in a UITextView that exceeds the height of the screen in portrait. Scroll to a position in the text and rotate to landscape. Sometimes the position is maintained but not all the time. When landscape is then switched back to portrait the contentOffset.y is changed back to 0. Given the two orientations it is understandable that the contentOffSet.y position will change as landscape reduces the height of the textView considerably. Text is also wider meaning fewer lines. It shouldn't change, but it does!

Comment: And scrollViews do not maintain a contentOffset this is easy to tell if you have ever used an iPhone before and changed orientations